My cat likes to claw my feet when it is under a blanket
My cat has this behavior where anytime he sees my feet on the bed especially if it under a blanket, regardless of where he is in the room, he will jump to the bed and use his claws to dig deep into my skin. I have read posts where they say you can direct their attention to other things but they don't work. He is so heavily fixated on my feet that I don't let him in my room at nights as I never get a good night's rest if he is. I have got scratches and cuts all over my feet that I am beginning to consider taking him returning him to the shelter.
Any tips on what I can do to avert the situation?

Age? If young, he may not realize that his claws are reaching you.

he is 2 yrs old

Very young adult, then. Still learning the world. Until he learns to keep his claws back when playing with you, you may want to pay a bit more attention to keeping his claws trimmed. Blunter ends do less damage than needles. Remember that he isn't trying to hurt you; he is just wrestling playfully as he would with another cat, and hasn't entirely figured out that our skins are more tender and not protected by fur. How you react also makes a difference; if you can push into the grab rather than pulling away, the claws don't snag.  Meanwhile see other answers about training/teaching cats.

Around here, we call this game "Blanket Monster." Cats generally love to pounce and attack things moving around under a blanket; it's oddly particularly appealing, and nearly universally so, especially with younger cats with a lot of energy like yours.
To your cat, this is a game, and he doesn't know he's causing you pain. To start off, if you aren't keeping his claws trimmed, I'd strongly recommend getting him (and yourself) into that routine. Blunting the tips of their claws can help with pain and injury while you train him to be more careful with them, and it's good for housecats long-term in general.
After trimming, stick your hand under the blanket and let him play with it. This might seem counterproductive, but stick with me here. You'll let him pounce and wrestle your hand, but if he bites or claws, loudly yell "Ow!" and stop the game immediately. This is similar to how cats learn to control their claws in a litter or group--if they claw (or bite) too hard, the other kitten will yelp and stop playing. It'll take some time, but your cat will start learning to control himself. He'll also start learning when you're actively engaging in the "blanket monster" game, and when you're just trying to rest.
Additionally to this, start wearing him down more with play, especially in the evening before bed. Get a wand toy (target on a string attached to a stick) that you can use to get him good and tired, then give him a bit of food and head to bed. You may think he's an "adult" at two years, but cats that age still have a lot of "kitten" energy and remain very active; direct that activity somewhere other than your feet to burn it off.
If possible, try adding a thicker blanket, too; something that's harder for him to get his claws (and teeth) through so further attacks on your feet will be more of an annoyance than an actual pain while he learns when it is and isn't appropriate to attack.
Cats are smarter than a lot of people give them credit for, and are definitely capable of learning. Training them is different from training dogs, who are motivated by "pleasing their pack mates," but using behaviors that directly affect him can work well--engaging in actual play is a benefit, and that play stopping isn't, so he'll work out how to keep the play going, and with that learn to stop using his claws on the "blanket monster."

At 2 years, my Siamese was still hiding behind the doors so she could pounce out and grab my ankle as I went by... But she had learned to hold back the claws, and we had both learned to distinguish between grab, nip, and bite.
